# How do you enforce a custom password policy on LUKS FDE (Ubuntu 22)?

Tags: ubuntu, security, luks, password-policy

I need to enforce a strong custom password policy for LUKS FDE on Ubuntu 22.

I have successfully enforced it on the user account level by modifying `/etc/pam.d/common-password`. But the restrictions in this file do not get applied when changing a LUKS password via `cryptsetup`. `cryptsetup` seems to completely ignore this file, and I cannot find any information about applying custom password requirements to LUKS specifically.

Is there a way I can achieve this? This is probably a niche question but it is a hard requirement for my organization.

EDIT: Modifying `/etc/security/pwquality.conf` does not seem to work either, at least not on its own -- it does check for pw quality when changing the root password, but not for the `cryptsetup` commands specifically, when changing a LUKS keyslot pw.

In some of the docs I see this:

```
   --force-password
          Do not use password quality checking for new LUKS passwords.

          This   option   applies   only  to  luksFormat,  luksAddKey  and
          luksChangeKey and is ignored  if  cryptsetup  is  built  without
          password quality checking support.

          For  more info about password quality check, see the manual page
          for pwquality.conf(5) and passwdqc.conf(5).
```

This is interesting. The implication here is that Ubuntu's `cryptsetup` has been built *without* "password quality checking support."

So I guess maybe the question is, is there a way to enable password quality check in `cryptsetup`, by altering some kind of config or running a command? Or is this parameter hard-coded into Ubuntu's `cryptsetup` implementation, and unable to be modified?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like cryptosetup makes use of libpwquality which is different to the PAM files you were looking at. It's config file is usually found at `/etc/security/pwquality.conf`.

And the man page is [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pwquality.conf)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this as well over the weekend. Unfortunately modifications to this file to not get applied to the cryptsetup command, at least on Ubuntu with out-of-the-box FDE.